# How to parse JSON that has inner layers using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I can eval simple JSON with javascript.

```
var json = '{"amount":"50","id":"3"}';
var out = eval("{" + json + "}");
```

Now I am using JPA with REST and JSON-nized query result would include table name which makes
JSON having inner JSON so simple eval wouldn't work.

```
{"inventory":{"amount":"50","id":"3"}}
```

I've looked around the web for solution but can't find my case.
Should I just do string manipulation and extract `{"amount":"50","id":"3"}` part?
Or is there other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is another (better) way! Use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_JSON_in_Firefox#Parsing_JSON.c2.a0strings) to parse your JSON and get your object out:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
//then, for example...
var amount = obj.inventory.amount;
```

For older browsers (IE <8 for example) without native `JSON` support, include [`json2.js`](http://www.json.org/js.html) so this above still works.

Answer (score 1):

Even this should work:

```
var json = '{"inventory":{"amount":"50","id":"3"}}';
var out = eval("{" + json + "}");

alert(out.inventory.amount);
```

But better to use [JSON.parse](http://www.json.org/js.html)

Answer (score 0):

Aniway, I think that the proper way to perform a simple eval is to have the json string surrounded with parenthesis, not curly brackets...

var out = eval("(" + json + ")");

Cf. https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json.js :

```
// In the third stage we use the eval function to compile the text into a
// JavaScript structure. The '{' operator is subject to a syntactic ambiguity
// in JavaScript: it can begin a block or an object literal. We wrap the text
// in parens to eliminate the ambiguity.

                j = eval('(' + text + ')');
```